# Where do I initial declare the FQDN?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I'm pretty new to this, but I'm setting up a private LAMP server for my small organization. I made a webapp that runs on Apache. Currently I can access the server on a different devices using the ip address. But I want to access it with a private domain name such as `example.com`. I found out that you can host a private DNS server. 
Im using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide to help. But I dont really understand it fully yet. One problem is I dont know where the FQDN should initially be define. Should it be inside my apache server config or the DNS server that I'm trying to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should it be inside my apache server config or the DNS server that I'm
>   trying to setup?

Yes, you should define the `ServerName` parameter in your VirtualHost configuration. At first, create a configuration file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` named `example.com.conf` and add the content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
    ServerName example.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

Change your `/var/www/` to your `DocumentRoot` and add any other directories of your site in the VirtualHost configuration. And then enable the site:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
```

Restart apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In case, you don't want to host a DNS server, just define this in `/etc/hosts` of your computer and any others you want them to have access:

```
IP_address example.com
```

If you need any further help to install a local DNS server, tell me.

Comment: Ohhhhhh.  I had setup the ServerName earlier but my brain never made that connection. Thanks, I will definitely keep that in mind.  I think you helped me with my last question as well :).

Comment: I am glad you've got it connected now. I think you should update the title corresponding to your real question instead so that fellows could look up just in case. Thanks for accepting my question! :-)

Comment: You should probably edit /etc/hosts too, so that your servers IP address is the proper one and not 127.0.1.1, as that is a hack for mobile computers that end up in other networks and also sometimes without any network at all. A "proper" LAN should also have a resolving DNS and a master DNS. But for smal LANs that is an overkill.